# Django CMS pages not visible after server restart

Tags: django-cms

I've been using django-cms to build a simple website for my GF. I was editing the base template and for some reason my changes were not going through, so I restarted the nginx server script only to find out to my horror, that I can't see any of the page content anymore, only their names in the tree in the admin interface. If I try to go to a page, it claims the page does not exist.

I thought maybe there is something wrong with the setup so I ran fix-tree and migrate (which might have been an error on my part) and now even the page names are not visible anymore in the admin interface. The pages and their contents are in the database, but they are not accessible anymore.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? What could be a possible cause / solution for this? Any ideas where to look

My guess is that something was wrong with the setup or perhaps I had a wrong version of some package and then I didn't run into trouble until I restarted.

I would love to have all those pages back especially that they still exist in the DB. Will be eternally grateful for any help.

**EDIT**

I just tried creating a new page. I was able to do this without any errors, the page is visible in the database but it is not visible in on the "Pages" page and the page slug gives an 404 error.

**EDIT 2**

Here's the requirements.txt

```
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.2.7
aldryn-boilerplates==0.7.4
aldryn-bootstrap3==1.0.10
aldryn-categories==1.0.3
aldryn-common==1.0.4
aldryn-newsblog==1.2.4
aldryn-people==1.2.1
aldryn-reversion==1.0.9
aldryn-style==1.1.1
aldryn-translation-tools==0.2.1
aldryn-video==1.0.0
Babel==2.3.4
backport-collections==0.1
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.8.15
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-appdata==0.1.5
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.2.5
django-durationfield==0.5.2
django-filer==1.2.4
django-formtools==1.0
django-mptt==0.8.6
django-parler==1.6.5
django-phonenumber-field==1.1.0
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-reversion==1.8.7
django-sekizai==0.10.0
Django-Select2==4.3.2
django-sortedm2m==1.3.2
django-taggit==0.21.2
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.3
djangocms-attributes-field==0.1.1
djangocms-column==1.6.0
djangocms-file==1.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.5.1
djangocms-inherit==0.2.1
djangocms-installer==0.8.7
djangocms-link==1.8.2
djangocms-picture==0.2.0
djangocms-style==1.7.0
djangocms-teaser==0.2.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.1.0
djangocms-video==1.0.0
easy-thumbnails==2.3
gevent==1.1rc3
greenlet==0.4.9
gunicorn==18.0
html5lib==0.9999999
jsonfield==1.0.3
lxml==3.6.4
micawber==0.3.3
phonenumbers==7.5.2
phonenumberslite==7.5.2
Pillow==3.3.1
psycopg2==2.6.1
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-slugify==1.2.0
pytz==2016.6.1
six==1.10.0
tzlocal==1.2.2
Unidecode==0.4.19
virtualenv==15.0.1
webencodings==0.5
YURL==0.13
```

And here's the settings file:

```
import os

gettext = lambda s: s
DATA_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
"""
Django settings for anninsivut project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.14.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'VERY SECRET'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.site.com', ]

# Application definition





ROOT_URLCONF = 'anninsivut.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'anninsivut.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases




# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'anninsivut', 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'anninsivut', 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'anninsivut', 'common_static'),

)
SITE_ID = 1

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'anninsivut', 'templates'), ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.core.context_processors.debug',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.core.context_processors.media',
                'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.core.context_processors.tz',
                'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
                'django.core.context_processors.static',
                'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
                'aldryn_boilerplates.context_processors.boilerplate',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
                'aldryn_boilerplates.template_loaders.AppDirectoriesLoader',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (

    # 'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware'
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'cms',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'treebeard',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'djangocms_style',
    'djangocms_column',
    'djangocms_file',
    'djangocms_googlemap',
    'djangocms_inherit',
    'djangocms_link',
    'djangocms_picture',
    'djangocms_teaser',
    'aldryn_video',
    'reversion',
    'aldryn_apphooks_config',
    'aldryn_boilerplates',
    'aldryn_categories',
    'aldryn_common',
    'aldryn_translation_tools',
    'aldryn_newsblog',
    'aldryn_people',
    'aldryn_reversion',
    'aldryn_bootstrap3',
    'parler',
    'sortedm2m',
    'taggit',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'filer',
    'anninsivut'
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('en', gettext('en')),
)

ALDRYN_BOILERPLATE_NAME = 'bootstrap3'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'aldryn_boilerplates.staticfile_finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    1: [
        {
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            'code': 'en',
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'public': True,
    },
}

THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.colorspace',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.autocrop',
    # 'easy_thumbnails.processors.scale_and_crop',  # disable this one
    'filer.thumbnail_processors.scale_and_crop_with_subject_location',
    'easy_thumbnails.processors.filters',
)

CMS_TEMPLATES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('page.html', 'Page'),
    ('feature.html', 'Page with Feature')
)

CMS_PERMISSION = True

CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'anninsivut_DB',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': '',
        'USER': 'user'
    }
}
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'name@domain.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'name@domain.com'
ADMINS = (
    ('Your name', 'your email address'),
)
MIGRATION_MODULES = {

}
```

@Paulo Thanks for asking for these. Now that I looked at the requirements and settings file, I see that the requirements file I had on my local Pycharm dir had not synced with the one on the server. At some point I must've accidentally upgraded to Django 1.9 in the venv of the server. Now I *guess* that when I restarted that's when the Django-CMS picked up the change and lost the page contents. Then when I saw the loss and downgraded back to 1.8, that's when I lost the page names as well on the pages tree. I'll start by going through the changes between the two and also see if the packages are up to date with what they should be.

Comment: Hi, this may not be very helpful to resolve your immediate situation but have you thought about using a more "packaged" Django CMS experience? For example, the Aldryn Desktop (https://www.divio.com/en/) makes it much easier both for local development and deployment. (I am not affiliated to them in any way apart from being an user of the platform)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have considered it and I actually started with Aldryn, but then wanted to get more familiar with the inner workings of both Django and Django-CMS. Well, better be careful with what you wish for; now have to setup a debugging env and dig in...

Comment: Hello @tarikki, please update your question with your requirements file and settings.py

Answer (score 1):

OK I managed to fix. After stepping through the code in the debugger in Pycharm, I realized I accidentally commented out the

`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'`

line in settings with made Django revert back to LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us', and that why it couldn't find the pages.

I also had a syncing problem between PyCharm and the deployment server, which is why the `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'` was **not** commented out in the settings.py I posted here.

So in short:

TIL that the language code must match in both

`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'`

and

`CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            'code': 'en',
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'public': True,
    },
}`